# Pybrain simple feedforward network not outputting expected values

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

I am trying to use pybrain to output rgb values. The input layer takes an array of rgb values, and all hidden layers are linear models. I would have expected the network to output rgb values. However, the output of this network turns out to be an array of values that are no where near within the range of 0:255.
The images are about 25 different .jpg images of a bull. Each image is a flattened array of length 575280. I was hoping the network would converge on an image that ends up resembling a bull.

```
import numpy as np
from pybrain.structure import FeedForwardNetwork, LinearLayer, SigmoidLayer, GaussianLayer, TanhLayer
from pybrain.structure import FullConnection, BiasUnit
import testabull

bull_x = 510
bull_y = 398
bull_flat = 575280

n = FeedForwardNetwork()

bias_unit = BiasUnit()
in_layer = LinearLayer(bull_flat)
hidden_A = LinearLayer(5)
hidden_B = LinearLayer(10)
out_layer = LinearLayer(bull_flat)

n.addInputModule(in_layer)
n.addModule(hidden_A)
n.addModule(hidden_B)
n.addOutputModule(out_layer)
n.addModule(bias_unit)

in_to_hidden = FullConnection(in_layer, hidden_A)
hidden_to_hidden = FullConnection(hidden_A, hidden_B)
hidden_to_out = FullConnection(hidden_B, out_layer)
bias_to_hidden = FullConnection(hidden_B, out_layer)

n.addConnection(in_to_hidden)
n.addConnection(hidden_to_hidden)
n.addConnection(bias_to_hidden)
n.addConnection(hidden_to_out)

n.sortModules()


bull_img_array = testabull.crop_the_bull_images('../../imgs/thebull/')

trainable_array = [] ## an array of flattened images
for im in bull_img_array:
    flat_im = np.array(im).flatten()
    trainable_array.append(flat_im)

print n
print n.activate(trainable_array[0])

output = None
for a in trainable_array:
    output = n.activate(a)
print output, len(output)
```

If anyone has any tips I would be very greatful.

Comment: `print output` -> [ 1039728.7439811  -2709035.59004357   181299.70423675 ...,
 -2346161.70897572  2502290.25359657  -404511.80700278]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off there are two issues here, one you need to scale your outputs between 0 and 255. You can do this with some transformation afterwards. By taking the max and min value, then transposing between 0 and 255.

On the other hand this network will likely not learn what you'd like it to, your hidden layers are using Linear Layers. This is not very useful, as the weights themselves form a linear transformation. You'll essentially end up with a linear function. ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ2.html#A_act

I would recommend using a SigmoidLayer for your hidden layers, this of course squashes the values between 0 and 1. You can correct this in the output layer by multiplying by 255. Either via a fixed layer or just transforming the values afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to normalize the outputs between 0:255 using the sigmoid layers. And you are right, the network just produces an image that looks like random RGB values. Would using some sort of back propagation help my cause? Please excuse my terminology if it is incorrect. I am basically wondering if I might compare the output of the network to the image of the bull, compute the error, and then update the weights. Might this result in an image that resembles a bull? Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, correct, you'd want to use a training algorithm of some kind, back propagation would be a good start. I don't know if the output would resemble a bull, depends on your training data; and the local minima/maxima you will be at. That's the beauty and the beast of machine learning :)

Pybrain has some documentation for training (granted its documentation isn't great), it's been awhile since I've worked with it; give it a shot and see what happens. http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/training.html